# Download excel file from share point library using SSIS

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, business-intelligence

I made connection with Share Point with oData Source. After that I got Collection and Under collection excel files are placed.

How to download excel file from  Collection ?

Comment: A SharePoint library can also be mapped as a network drive, or accessed as a file share (because of WebDAV).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any options yourself? Please go through this link first to understand how should you be asking questions -[How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
HTTP Connection Manager and a script task should do the job. There are some custom components on codeplex to download the sharepoint lists  (unless they are https connections) using SSIS.

Comment: I connected with share point using oData source. So after That I nedd suggestion. What is next step to download files under a collection.

Comment: Document libraries contain documents. Why use OData at all? These documents are the same as any other web page, *and* they can be accessed as files on a file share